# htaccess RewriteRule for subdomain redirection by language

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website in English `http://example.com`

Then I want to add code for a redirect to my subdomain PT language `http://pt.example.com` if the browser language is PT

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (pt) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://pt.example.com [R,L]
```

When I add this I get a redirect loop in the browser.

I have tried `example.com/pt` and get the same error from the browser.

Comment: Since you are redirecting with the `R` flag (instead of a rewrite), the redirection makes a new HTTP request which processes/matches this rule. You likely just need to add a condition that checks if `%{HTTP_HOST}` starts with `pt.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a RewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^pt\.example\.com
```